# Agile Uploader (resizes image before upload on the server) - no image in POST data at all?

Tags: image, post, file-upload, image-manipulation, image-uploading

I want to use [Agile Uploader](http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html) to resize images before upload on my server.

But when I try to upload image on server it does nothing... I mean that there is no image in POST data. I've checked POST and there is no items at all. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery.flash.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/unrelated.css" />
    <script src="/static/js/agile-uploader-3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/agile-uploader.css" />
</head>
<body>

<form action="/test" method="post" id="singularDemo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="single"></div>
</form>

<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('agileUploaderSWF').submit();">Submit</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#single').agileUploaderSingle({
            formId:'singularDemo',
            progressBarColor:'#3b5998',
            flashVars:{
                firebug:true,
                form_action:'/test',                
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Most code part taken from their [demo](http://www.shift8creative.com/agile-uploader/examples/single.php).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit the `process.php` file, where you'll define the remote upload folder!
and then modify the `form_action` in: `"form_action: process.php"`